# Perl capture and add to end of string

Tags: regex, perl

I have a file with a lot of lines like this:

```
ChrVIII_A_nidulans_FGSC_A4  AspGD   gene    3861520 3863875 .   +   .   ID=AN0338;Name=AN0338;Gene=CYP680A1;Note=Putative%20cytochrome%20P450;orf_classification=Uncharacterized;Alias=ANIA_00338,ANID_00338
```

My region of interest is `;Gene=_____;` -- the stuff between the `=` and `;`.

If this region exists, I want to append it to the end of the line with a , attached to the front. If it does not exist I want to print the line anyway!

```
ChrVIII_A_nidulans_FGSC_A4  AspGD   gene    3861520 3863875 .   +   .   ID=AN0338;Name=AN0338;Gene=CYP680A1;Note=Putative%20cytochrome%20P450;orf_classification=Uncharacterized;Alias=ANIA_00338,ANID_00338,CYP680A1
```

This is what I tried in Perl and I don't know why it doesn't work.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
open(SOURCE,"<annotation.gff") or die "Source file not found!\n";

my $line1;
foreach $line1(<SOURCE>)            #iterating over SOURCE file
{
if($line1=~/Gene\=([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)\;/)
printf "$line1,$1";
}
else {printf "$line1";}
}
```

Can anyone show me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I forgot to type the } in this snippet I posted but yes a lot of errors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's go through your code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

Good. However, trying to run your code gives:

> `syntax error at ss.pl line 9, near ")
>   printf"
>   syntax error at ss.pl line 11, near "else"`

which means you did not post the code you ran, so we can't really trust it. Don't do that. Reduce your problem to a small, self-contained script others can run.

```
open(SOURCE,"<annotation.gff") or die "Source file not found!\n";
```

- Don't use bareword filehandles such as `SOURCE`. Instead, use lexical filehandles.
- Don't hard code the name of the file you are trying to open. Doing so makes it hard to accurately convey the name of the file your program failed to open in case of a failure.
- In the error message, include actual error your program encountered, rather than hardcoding your unwarranted assumptions.
- Don't use the two argument form of `open`, especially if you are going to want the flexibility to specify file names as command line arguments instead of having to edit the script every time you get a new input file. That is, use

  ```
  my $annotation_file = 'annotation.gff';
  open my $source, '<', $annotation_file
      or die "Failed to open annotation source '$annotation_file': $!";
  ```
- Don't declare the iteration variable for a loop outside the scope of the loop.That is, instead of:

  ```
  my $line1;
  foreach $line1 ( ... )
  ```

  use

  ```
  foreach my $line1 ( ... )
  ```
- But, of course, you should not use a `for` loop to iterate over the contents of a file because doing so makes your program *slurp* (i.e. read the entire contents of) the file into memory as a list of lines. This makes the memory footprint of your program depend on the size of its input instead of the size of the longest line. Also, drop the `1` suffix: You are iterating through *every* line in the file, not just the first one.

  ```
   while (my $line = <$source>) {
  ```
- Don't use `printf` if you are just printing plain strings. That is, instead of `printf "$line1,$1"`, use `print "$line,$1\n"`.
- And, that brings us to another problem. When you read the line, you never remove the newline off its end. Therefore, the string you print is `"...\n..."` which creates the effect of *prepending* the captured string to the beginning of the following line.

That brings us to something that works:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $annotation_file = 'annotation.gff';

open my $source, '<', $annotation_file
    or die "Cannot open annotation source '$annotation_file': $!";

while (my $line = <$source>) {
    if( $line =~ /Gene = ( [^;]+ ) ;/x ) {
        chomp $line;
        print join(',' => $line, $1), "\n";
    }
    else {
        print $line;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
open(my $fh, '<', 'annotation.gff') or die $!;

while (<$fh>) {
    chomp;
    /Gene=([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)\;/ and $_ .= ",$1";
    print "$_\n";
}

close $fh;
```

Comment: Fixed the answer